# How to enable breadcrumb or back button

Tags: admin-on-rest

How to enable breadcrumb and back button.

Example for back button: In admin-on-rest demo site, If user click a CUSTOMERS in segments page it will goes to customer page with specific filter. I want add a back button in the customer page to come back to the segment page again.

Example for Breadcrumb: If user search a employee name in a location. then it should display like Location Name > Dept Name > Unit Name > Emp ID > Emp Name.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Most AOR pages accept an Actions prop. You can use that to redirect to any custom location or to the last location in history.